# How to resize toggle button?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, toggle

I have a HTML page with toggle button having its CSS but area of toggle button and its length are deviating from initial position.

[image]

When I press toggle it shifts with a different left margin and length also changes.

[image]

Here's a code snippet of what I've done

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #2ab934;
  left: 31px;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}


/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/

.EMEA {
  display: none;
}

.EMEA,
.AMERICAS {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked+.slider .EMEA {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.slider .AMERICAS {
  display: none;
}


/*--------- END --------*/


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
  <div class="slider round">
   <!--ADDED HTML -->
    <span class="EMEA">EMEA</span>
    <span class="AMERICAS">AMERICAS</span>
    <!--END-->
  </div>
</label>
```

How can I bring `EMEA` toggle same length as that of `AMERICAS` and without changing its position?

Comment: You need to fix the min-width for the toggles. The width difference is coming because of text length of AMERICAS and EMEA

Comment: can you suggest edit in code?

Comment: Try adding this
  
  .EMEA, .AMERICAS
  {
    min-width: 50px;
    ...
  }

Comment: Or .switch { min-width: 120px; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the `left: 31px` from `input:checked + .slider`.
2. Add `31px` to `transform: translateX(55px)` so it becomes `transform: translateX(86px)` in `input:checked + .slider:before`.

Updated working example:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { display:none; }

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(86px);
}

/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/
.EMEA
{
  display: none;
}

.EMEA, .AMERICAS
{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked + .slider .EMEA
{ display: block; }

input:checked + .slider .AMERICAS
{ display: none; }

/*--------- END --------*/

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
  <div class="slider round">
    <span class="EMEA">EMEA</span>
    <span class="AMERICAS">AMERICAS</span>
  </div>
</label>
```